# How do I pull data from another tab/worksheet based on a column value in Excel 2019?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

[image: Sample Sheet]

I am trying to create separate sheets on the same workbook that automatically update for all our sales based on one column value which is Column D. We get data from a master sheet in the same workbook that gets updated daily. So basically fill up the worksheet with data from master worksheet based on one column value. Example, the cash worksheet should contain all sales where D="Cash".
Worksheets to create and auto-fill.

1. Cash
2. Check
3. Online

I know how to do this in Google Sheets, but not in Excel 2019. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely some setup in the pivot table function, but I don't have that enabled currently, and I would do it this way anyway. A nested function with cell references by sheet and column names.

I entered your sample spreadsheet.
I created the summary sheet with these results:

```
 Cash  1600
 Check  400
 Online 400
```

The function is as follows, with the word "Cash" exchanged in each location for the appropriate value:

```
=SUM(IF(Sheet1!D:D="Cash",Sheet1!F:F,0))
```

Unpacking the "nest" here, if column D on Sheet1 has a value of "Cash", then return the value of column F on Sheet1, if it does not, then return a value of 0. That is the IF function. It is enclosed in a SUM() function, so the numbers are totaled in the final value of the complete function.

Hope this helps!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actrually, I needed a list of all the sales and not a sum. sorry I wasnt very good at explaining.